# Is there a way to format output with grep or egrep with a separator between instances of the output?

Tags: text-processing, grep, output

I have a dataset  that has a large amount of data in it:

```
ID Number:  A00001
Name:       John Smith
Address:    123 Any Street
City:       AnyTown
State:      Ohio
Zip:        12345

ID Number:  A00002
Name:       Jane Doe
Address:    123 Any Street
City:       AnyTown
State:      Nebraska
Zip:        12346

ID Number:  C00003
Name:       Jim Shields
Address:    123 Any Street
City:       AnyTown
State:      Alaska
Zip:        12347

ID Number:  D11111
Name:       Mary Ellis
Address:    123 Any Street
City:       AnyTown
State:      Nevada
Zip:        12348
```

and I want to pull data out and separate it so it appears like this:

```
ID Number:  A00001
Name:       John Smith
Zip:        12345
=========================
ID Number:  A00002
Name:       Jane Doe
Zip:        12346
=========================
ID Number:  C00003
Name:       Jim Shields
Zip:        12347
=========================
ID Number:  D11111
Name:       Mary Ellis
Zip:        12348
=========================
```

I have tried about every grep and egrep option I could find, but the closest I could get was putting a blank line (new line) between every line of output.

Comment: This is not what you need, but might be relevant to people stumbling on your post: `grep` allows for changing the block separator `--` that is used in case `-A` or `-B` is applied via `--group-separator=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` is a pattern matching tool, not a text reformatting tool.  Use something like `sed`, `awk`, or `perl` instead.  For example:

```
$ awk '/^(ID Number|Name|Zip):/;
       /^[[:blank:]]*$/ { print "=========================" }'
ID Number:  A00001
Name:       John Smith
Zip:        12345
=========================
ID Number:  A00002
Name:       Jane Doe
Zip:        12346
=========================
ID Number:  C00003
Name:       Jim Shields
Zip:        12347
=========================
ID Number:  D11111
Name:       Mary Ellis
Zip:        12348
```

The `[[:blank:]]*` is to match any lines that **look** like they're empty but actually contain horizontal space like spaces or tabs....which is more common than you'd think because it's something that's hard to see with your eyes alone.

or, with perl:

```
perl -l -n -e 'print if /^(ID Number|Name|Zip):/;
               print "=" x 25  if /^\h*$/' input.txt
```

or with `sed`.  First, if you have GNU sed or some other sed that understands perl RE's `\h` for "horizontal space":

```
sed -n -E -e '/^(ID Number|Name|Zip):/p; s/^\h*$/=========================/p' input.txt
```

Otherwise, with any sed:

```
sed -n -E -e '/^(ID Number|Name|Zip):/p; s/^[[:blank:]]*$/=========================/p' input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, Cas, but it's still not quite there. 
When I cat the file and pipe it to awk with your response, it ONLY prints the lines with the = signs:  
```code
cat file.txt | awk '/^(ID Number|Name|Zip):/; /^[[:blank:]]*$/ { print "=====" }'

=====

=====

=====

Comment: If that's happening, then it's because the sample text you posted is not the same as the text you're using.   All 4 of the one-liners above work with the sample text.  I wouldn't have posted them if I hadn't tested them.   Perhaps your file is from a Windows machine with CRLF line endings instead of LF? no...if that was the case, the `=====` lines would be the lines NOT printed.

Comment: It's actually Ubuntu, but I think you are right.... the text in the file actually has space between the key and the ':'   Name<12 spaces>:  value    how can I account for a variable amount of space between the keys and the ':'

Comment: Neve rmind, I just took the colon OUT, and it worked PERFECTLY!!! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: with perl (or anything else that undertands `\h`), change the regex to `/^(ID Number|Name|Zip)\h*:/`.  Or use `\s*` instead of `\h*`.   Otherwise use `[[:blank:]]*`.     If the keys might also be indented, also add `\h*`, `\s*`, or `[[:blank:]]*` immediately after the `^`.

Comment: In my script, the \s* worked as well. Thank you again. I appreciate the assistance, as it is obvious that I struggle with regex....  :)

Comment: In Perl RE (and anything that borrows from it, like PCRE), `\s` is **any** white space, vertical (like newlines) and horizontal (like spaces).  `\h` is a subset of `\s`, only horizontal whitespace. and `\v` is only vertical whitespace.  BTW, some regex engines implement perl's meaning of \s but not perl's \h or \v. In `vim`, for example, `\v` enable's "very magic" mode in a regex, so less things need to be backslash-escaped to become "magical" - i.e. have a special, non-literal meaning...kind of like the difference between Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) and Extended Regular Expressions, (ERE)

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
    split(tgts,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        tags[tmp[i]]
    }
    sep = "========================="
}
$1 in tags
!NF { print sep }
END { if (NF) print sep }
```

```
$ awk -v tgts='ID Number:Name:Zip' -f tst.awk file
ID Number:  A00001
Name:       John Smith
Zip:        12345
=========================
ID Number:  A00002
Name:       Jane Doe
Zip:        12346
=========================
ID Number:  C00003
Name:       Jim Shields
Zip:        12347
=========================
ID Number:  D11111
Name:       Mary Ellis
Zip:        12348
=========================
```

```
$ awk -v tgts='City:State' -f tst.awk file
City:       AnyTown
State:      Ohio
=========================
City:       AnyTown
State:      Nebraska
=========================
City:       AnyTown
State:      Alaska
=========================
City:       AnyTown
State:      Nevada
=========================
```

Answer (score 0):

Treating each section as a record and each line within a section as a field, it seems you want to output the first two and the last field of each record, with a line of equal signs to delimit the records in the output.

```bsh
$ awk -F'\n' -v OFS='\n' -v RS='' -v ORS='\n=========================\n' '{ print $1,$2,$NF }' file
ID Number:  A00001
Name:       John Smith
Zip:        12345
=========================
ID Number:  A00002
Name:       Jane Doe
Zip:        12346
=========================
ID Number:  C00003
Name:       Jim Shields
Zip:        12347
=========================
ID Number:  D11111
Name:       Mary Ellis
Zip:        12348
=========================
```

The command line first sets the values of the input and output field separator to a newline character. Doing so ensures that fields are individual lines in both input and output.

Then the record separator is set to the empty string, which enables "paragraph mode," i.e., it enables us to read a section of text delimited by one or more empty lines as a single record.

The output record separator is then set to equal signs, with newlines at either end.

The actual code prints the first, second, and last fields from each record.  You could also use `$6` in place of `$NF`.